# What does “their” mean in this sentence?

Tags: possessive-pronouns

What does the last segment here mean?Who does "their(1-2)" references?

|subject| + **verb** + \direct object\ + preposition (usually to or for) + /indirect object/

|those invested with responsibility for others| **will abuse** \their(1) position\ for /their(2) own ends/.

> By no means do liberals believe that individuals are infallible in
> this respect, but the belief in reason builds into liberalism a strong
> bias against paternalism. Not only does paternalism prevent
> individuals from making their own moral choices and, if necessary,
> from learning from their own mistakes, but it also creates the
> prospect that those invested with responsibility for others will abuse
> **their** position for **their** own ends.

[image]

Comment: _What does the last segment of the sentence mean?_ **Their** refers to the subject of the clause, **those invested with responsibility for others**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... [those] invested with responsibility for others [will abuse] [their position] [for their own ends].

[*abuse* takes sense 6](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/abuse#google_vignette):

> 6. VERB
>    If you abuse something, you use it in a wrong way or for a bad purpose.
>    He showed how the rich and powerful can abuse their position.

Your example uses this common definition and says that those people
making decisions for another group will use **their power to meet their own needs**.